# syntax error : 1064 , when creating a stored procedure on XAMPP

Tags: stored-procedures, syntax, mariadb

platform: MySQL on XAMPP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE percent(erp varchar(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE percent DECIMAL(10,2);
SELECT AVG(sub1 + sub2 + sub3)
INTO percent
FROM marksheet
WHERE erp = erp;
END;
```

here i get the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

i expect correction to mysql query.

Comment: Read this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/

Comment: Also note the procedure name `percent` isn't an output variable. ref: [create procedure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-procedure/). Do you want this to be a [function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-function/)?